# Creating Community Ads

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I've created this post to track our community ads as they appear on other sites. The answers can be used for proposing new designs, the highest voted one will go on other sites (manually edited in place of the ones we already have on other sites). Feel free to make site specific ads as well. Currently all the ads are posted created by myself, and I'll edit them if a new ad becomes more popular.

Also feel free to leave constructive criticism in the comments.

### Ad Stats

**On either of these lists, please upvote our ads to make sure they appear.**

Our ad is posted and not yet active on:

- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/960) (Needs +3)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2186) (Needs +3)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17057/670112) (Needs +1)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9937) (Needs +2)
- [Info Sec](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2725/79056) (Needs +1)
- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4504/157776) (Needs +6)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3814) (Needs +1)

Our ad is currently active on:

- [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3734/74265) - [Stats](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3661)
- [Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1397/72990) - [Stats](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1369)
- [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2975) - [Stats](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2963)
- [Tex](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7318) - [Stats](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/7182)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8565/199039) - [Stats](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/8429)
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26490/453718) - [Stats](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/25812)
- [Crypto](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/932) - [Stats](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/843)

### Current Ad

Here is the current ad. The format for proposals should follow this template:

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

```
[![You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFwCm.png
  [2]: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com
```

### Proposal Requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

Comment: Thanks for your work on this!

Comment: We should do matheducators as well. There's probably a lot of overlap there.

Comment: @BenI. Currently, the [tag:community-ads] tag (which is required on all community ad posts) has [no posts](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads).

Comment: @BenI. Community Ads are only enabled on graduated sites (beta sites don't get them), so that's why Mathematics Educators has no ads post on meta.

Comment: @thesecretmaster It has been mentioned in chat before, I just wanted to repost it here so it's there where it should be: Could you make this a community wiki so others can edit in sites they posted an ad on?

Comment: @TuringTux Sadly, I can't make the question community wiki and the answers shouldn't be community wiki.

Comment: @heather Keep in mind that by posting ads, you've become the person maintaining those ads. Make sure to keep checking in here regularly, in case a different ad gets voted to the top. Also, I'd like to stay consistant in terms of which ad we post, and the goal of this meta question was to allow the community to determine the "best" ad and post that ad everywhere.

Comment: @thesecretmaster, I'm willing to keep checking here - I thought (from a comment in the chat) you wanted to put different ads on different sites, perhaps - I can change them to the proper one. Also, Mathematics is now active - it's at 6 upvotes.

Comment: Also, you're totally right about different ads on different sites. I'd forgot that discussion. I'll think of a way to organize that and edit that in later today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

```
[![You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFwCm.png
  [2]: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators]

```
  [![You can also join us in the CS room, http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59701/join-cs-educators][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6fyK.png
  [2]: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: Nice! However it seems to me as the text is a bit stretched (might be due to the font), especially when it is scaled down to 50%.

Comment: @TuringTux, I think it might be the font, yeah.

Comment: What font did you use?

Comment: @TuringTux "Ubuntu Mono"

Comment: Thank you! So it's probably just me (as the Ubuntu fonts are designed by professionals). Side note: Do you know [Hack](https://sourcefoundry.org/hack/)? I often use it for code.

Comment: @TuringTux, no, I don't know of Hack - I'll try to remember that, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Please keep in mind that ads should be relevant to the community they're posted in.**

Don't go spamming random websites. Community ads on X Stack Exchange are for topics that are of interest to the X community.

If computer science education is not relevant to X, then don't advertise on X Stack Exchange.

If computer science education is relevant to X, then make an ad that showcases CSE.SE **from the point of view of the X community**.

For an example of how to do it right, look at [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/lets-design-an-ad-for-our-site) — note how several sites have a variation on the same graphic design, but with a quote that's tailored to each community. Another example which sometimes stretches relevance a bit thin is [IoT](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/lets-advertise-with-community-ads/173#173).