# Creating Community Ads (2018 Edition)

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Well, almost a year since our conception and 'tis the season for community ads again! On all graduated sites, there are **Community Promotion Ads** which provide an opportunity for *relevant, useful* sites and tools to promote themselves with small ads.

Last year, we created 2 ads and simply posted them everywhere. That was ... not a correct or appropriate use of ads. Ads should be relevant to the community in which they appear, and so dumping the same ad everywhere **is not OK**. For more details, see [this answer on last years ads post](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/136/58).

All that said, I've created this post to track our community ads as we create them and post them on other sites. Here's how the system will work: Below, there will be a list of sites that we'd like to make ads for, and a list of posted ads. Anyone can volunteer to make an ad for a site, possibly one on the list or possibly a different site. *Remember: Taking the same ad and posting it for every site **is not permitted***. Once an ad is created, it should be posted as an answer on this question (**not** on the other sites community ad post). Once it's score is > 1, it will be posted on the target site. If there are multiple suggestions for a target site, only the highest voted will be posted.

### Sites which need ads

I've taken this list from last year:

- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com)
- [Info Sec](https://security.stackexchange.com)
- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com)
- [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com)
- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com)
- [Theoretical CS](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com)
- [Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com)
- [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com)

### Sites which have ads

- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8696/199039)
- [Computer Science](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1464/72990) (Both of last years ads were posted by a moderator. See [1](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1457/72990), [2](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1458/72990))
- Cryptography [moderator reposted last years ad](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1006)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2302/54822) (current score of 1)
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27879/386000) (current score -1)

### Sites which have active ads (score >= 6)

- [None right now]

### Ad Requirements

These are the **requirements** imposed by Stack Exchange for any community ads:

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

Comment: I'll draw something up

Comment: @ItamarG3 Just remember that it must be target-site specific.

Comment: Crypto has one posted for CSE already, https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1006/49285. Posted by one of their mods. It's last years recycled, so we might want to replace it.

Comment: Thanks @ping. It also at -1 now, so we probably want to replace it.

Comment: @thesecretmaster posted a math one

Comment: @thesecretmaster well... math is -1 as well

Answer (score 7):

[image: We'd be happy to welcome you!]

Comment: My idea is to use this for Theoretical CS and Computer Science Stack Exchange - therefore, I emphasized the "teaching" part.

Comment: A couple thoughts: You might want to have it say the "Stack Exchange" somewhere, and you might want different bckground images for CS and Theoretical CS.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Thank you for your feedback. I tried addressing your first point with a new version - is this better in your eyes?

Comment: I think it's great! I agree that it makes sense for all the CS-type site (CS, theoretical CS, maybe software engineering). Do you want to post it, or should I?

Comment: @thesecretmaster It would be nice if you could post it, please :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Hint: Caesar cipher]

Comment: This one is tailored for Cryptography Stack Exchange. The white text is caesar ciphered with k=5 and reads "Do you have ideas how to teach cryptography?" when decrypted. The text that should appear on hover once the ad is live (to view it now, click "edit") is "Bj'i gj mfuud yt bjqhtrj dtz!" and encrypted with the same key. Decrypted it reads "We'd be happy to welcome you!".

Comment: Personally, I really like it. But I'm kinda concerned that people will see it and get confused, so it might be better to have the decryption instructions in the mouseover text.

Comment: @thesecretmaster I see... Would a mouseover like "Hint: Try shifting each letter back in the alphabet 5 times" (or better formulated) be adequate?

Comment: We could also just try suggesting it and wait how the Crypto Stack Exchange community reacts in the comments.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Since it is a crypto community anyway, maybe just the mouse over hint of "Caesar cipher (5)" would be enough. It lets them_know_ what to do if they understand Caesar ciphers, and gives them a puzzle if they don't, which crypto folks probably love anyway.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Oh, I like this. Maybe we can go one step further and omit the "(5)"? It would still be possible to solve the puzzle in a very short time without this information, but it wouldn't be completely solved on hover (so there'd be still a little challenge).

Comment: @TuringTux Refresh and try the hover now.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Great :) I also changed the alt text so it will appear correctly if the ad gets posted and displayed.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Join the Computer Science Stack Exchange]

Comment: Why not use the real Mathematica logo?

Comment: It is the real one. I took the png from their site. The name "Mathematica" isn't here because it's copywrited and I can't bother looking if this is legal

Comment: Maybe you could make it a bit more explicit, e.g. "Answer questions about teaching mathematica"

Comment: I can't find that logo anywhere.  I can only find [these](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/SpikeyVersions.gif).

Comment: @BenI. took it from [here](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/?source=nav)

Comment: @thesecretmaster how about now?

Comment: Hm. I like it. I think it should read "Ask and Answer", but it's also find as is. Maybe worth adding CS and Mathematica, but I can't think of a good way to phrase it.

Comment: @ItamarG3 you can not copyright a word, but Mathematica is probably trademarked. The image will be copyright. With trademark, you have to avoid giving the impression that you represent the company.

Comment: @thesecretmaster I tried putting those inside the venn diagram, in each circle.

Comment: @ItamarG3 Last thing: You might want to put "CSEducators Stack Exchange" at the top or something. Beyond that, I think it's great.

Comment: @thesecretmaster i will do that later tlday

Comment: @thesecretmaster and then I didn't. oops. Maybe I'll have time today

Comment: @thesecretmaster done. Doing a physics now. And a math one. That one will soon be uploaded

Answer (score 3):

[image: We'd be happy to welcome you!]

Comment: This one is tailored for Software Engineering SE, therefore the different catchphrase.

Answer (score 2):

[image: mathhhh]

Comment: Which site is this for?  (Sorry, I don't recognize the symbol)

Comment: @BenI. Math. That's their icon. (taken from the sidebar: [q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644700/whats-new-in-higher-dimensions))

Comment: @BenI. I, personally, like this ad more than the [Mathematica one](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2302/54822)

Comment: I like this ad, but on my screen, I'm seeing some odd rendering glitches (like faint pixelated outlines bigger than the objects themselves). Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: @Aurora0001 that is so weird. I see that now as well. I'll fix it now

Comment: @Aurora0001 better?

Comment: Yep, looks good to me, @Itamar.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Join here!]